# Why is my budgeter's pie chart not working correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create a pie chart but it is not working. Instead, I am getting the error shown below my code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

inputted_payment = input("Type in how much money you made this month. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  ")
inputted_groceries = input("Type in how much money you spent on groceries this month. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  ")
inputted_gas = input("Type in how much money you spent on gas this month. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  ")
inputted_bills = input("Type in how much money you spent on bills. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  ")
inputted_restaurants = input("Type in how much money you spent on restaurants. Don't type any letters or symbols, Type decimals if needed.  ")
inputted_other_things = input("Type in how much money you spent on other things. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  ")
total_spent = inputted_bills + inputted_other_things + inputted_gas + inputted_groceries + inputted_restaurants
total_left = float(inputted_payment) - float(total_spent)

y = np.array([inputted_groceries, inputted_gas, inputted_bills, inputted_restaurants, inputted_other_things, total_left])
mylabels = ["Groceries", "Gas", "Bills", "Restaurants", "Other Things", "Money Left"]

print('''
Total Spendings''')
plt.pie(y, labels = mylabels)
plt.show()
```

Error message:

```py
ValueError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c9a2c4e52c53> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 print('''
     17 Total Spendings''')
---> 18 plt.pie(y, labels = mylabels)
     19 plt.show()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in pie(self, x, explode, labels, colors, autopct, pctdistance, shadow, labeldistance, startangle, radius, counterclock, wedgeprops, textprops, center, frame, rotatelabels, normalize, hatch)
   3194 
   3195         if np.any(x < 0):
-> 3196             raise ValueError("Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values")
   3197 
   3198         sx = x.sum()

ValueError: Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
total_spent = inputted_bills + inputted_other_things + inputted_gas + inputted_groceries + inputted_restaurants
```

You are [`concatenating`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp) strings, not adding values. Because `inputted_bills` to `inputted_restaurants`, all these variables are `string`s.

So this line: `total_left = float(inputted_payment) - float(total_spent)`  actually has a huge negative value output, which results in `ValueError: Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values`

To fix this issue, you should cast your input as `float` and then assign to variables as you are processing.

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

inputted_payment = float(input("Type in how much money you made this month. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  "))
inputted_groceries = float(input("Type in how much money you spent on groceries this month. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  "))
inputted_gas = float(input("Type in how much money you spent on gas this month. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  "))
inputted_bills = float(input("Type in how much money you spent on bills. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  "))
inputted_restaurants = float(input("Type in how much money you spent on restaurants. Don't type any letters or symbols, Type decimals if needed.  "))
inputted_other_things = float(input("Type in how much money you spent on other things. Don't type any letters or symbols. Type decimals if needed.  "))
total_spent = inputted_bills + inputted_other_things + inputted_gas + inputted_groceries + inputted_restaurants

total_left = inputted_payment - total_spent


y = np.array([inputted_groceries, inputted_gas, inputted_bills, inputted_restaurants, inputted_other_things, total_left])
mylabels = ["Groceries", "Gas", "Bills", "Restaurants", "Other Things", "Money Left"]

print('''Total Spendings''')
plt.pie(y, labels = mylabels)
plt.show()
```